# Bit Manipulation Hacker's Delight in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, bit-manipulation

I'm trying to get into the book "Hacker's Delight." The first formula in chapter 2 is `x & (x -1)` and is supposed to "turn off the rightmost 1-bit in a word producing 0 if none
(e.g. 01011000 -> 0101000)." I have no idea why someone would want to do this.

I translated this into python as
`bin(0b1011000 and (0b1011000 - 1))` and got
`'0b1010111'`. Is this correct?

I tried leaving out the "b" designating leading zeros and got this wild result `'0b11110110110100110111'`.

Am I close to correct?

Comment: `and` is not the same as `&`.

Comment: Generally, yes, absolutely,  but Python doesn't recognize &&, and I see no reason to switch languages to demonstrate that point.  This is for fun, I'm not a student, so why switch to C? @kaya3

Comment: `&&` is also not the same as `&`. You need to write `&` for a bitwise "and" operation; this is true in Python, not just in C.

Comment: @kaya3 point well taken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try these a few examples and see if you can tell the *correctness* yourself:

```py
>>>x = 15
>>>bin(x)
'0b1111'

>>>x & (x -1)
14
>>>bin(14)
'0b1110'

# now try this x = 10
>>>x = 10
>>>bin(x)
'0b1010'
>>>x & (x - 1)
8
>>>bin(8)
'0b1000`     # <---- see the rightmost bit is gone *rightmost 1*
```

Comment: Got it. I'm trying to get a deeper understanding of what's going on "under the hood" and the first two questions stopped me cold. Thank you!

Comment: The interesting question from the OP remains: why would someone want to do this?